.NET Set default datetime format for DTO and EF
I have a DTO with a DateTime property. When I use Swagger to send data to the endpoint it expects a DateTime in a specific format.
public class TimeStampDTO
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

When I check the swagger it expects a DateTime in a different format then specified in the DTO.
{
  "timestamp": "2024-09-27T09:31:42.291Z"
}

expected result:
{
  "timestamp": "2024-09-27 09:31:42"
}

I can't approach the endpoint right now because I can't serialize the Timestamp. How can I fix this?

The expectation is wrong. The ISO8601 format is the standard way of serializing dates in JSON. All JSON libraries can parse this format. Nothing is displayed here so the DisplayFormat attribute has no effect. The date serialization format is specified in RFC 7493

Why do you want to remove T? No libraries are affected by it, in fact some require it. The T can be removed for readability but that plays no part in an API payload. Swagger UI isn't an end-user UI, it's just a doc/test page that shows the contents of your API's OpenApi spec in a nice way and allows you to call the methods without trying to validate or format them. That means you have to ensure you enter the correct values as they'd appear in JSON

Did you assume that Swagger UI (or whatever you use) is an actual web form, and thus affected by DisplayAttribute? In reality, the entire UI is generated based on the contents of /swagger/v1/swagger.json. No display information is included in that document

If your endpoint stumbles over the standard json format then a problem is there and not in your swagger frontend.

You have mentioned EF in the title. Display format of a datetime should be of no concern to EF if not doing something wrong. That expresses even more that there is a problem in your endpoint code.

Adding to what @Ralf said, EF will, by default, persist DateTimes using an appropriate column type e.g. DATE or DATE2. There is no formatting associated with this. As others have stated DisplayFormatAttribute is only intended for rendering for human readability and will not have any effect on serialization in APIs or swagger.
